# strlen() doesn't work with $_POST

Tags: php

I am using this code in my `*.php` file

```
$check = $_POST['dati'];

 if (strlen($check) != 0) {
  // calculations
 }
 else {
   echo "contact me at <a href='mailto:myemail'></a>";
 }
```

The `dati` inside that POST is the name attribute of an input field. If the input has a length = 0, that echo must be displayed.

I have the same code in another part of my server and it works perfectly. I'm having troubles here because when the length of `dati` is 0, the script makes the calculations instead of showing the echo.

```
<input name="dati" id="dati" style="width:310px" type="text">
```

This is the code of the input. Any ideas?

Comment: Your `if` logic is flawed then. It goes to the calculation branch when strlen is 0, and does the echo when the strlen is not zero.

Comment: Yes sorry I failed while I was typing the code. I put the " != ". I still have the problem

Comment: did you try with '>' rather than, '==' or '!=' because the strlen function will return the length of the string, you want the if to be called and if it is less than zero the else to be called.

Comment: Yes but it doesn't work in any case :(

Comment: what is the value of: strlen($check) and what is $_POST['dati'] and what is the value of $check can you post that here please, thanks.

Comment: @AlbertoRossi Are you wanting to show a certain echo'ed message if the post is `0` or more? If so, why not do `if (strlen($check) == 0) {` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code works well as you can see here: http://codepad.org/fCvlokOJ and here http://codepad.org/t2TvFozt

```
<?php
$_POST['dati']= "text";

if (strlen($_POST['dati']) != 0) {
   echo" calculations";
 }
 else {
   echo "contact me at <a href='mailto:myemail'></a>";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the following example, if field is left blank, echo'ed message is "sorry".

If text entered, then Email link appears. **TESTED**

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))

$check = $_POST['dati'];

 if (strlen($check) == 0) {

echo "Sorry";

 }
 else {
   echo "Contact me at <a href='mailto:myemail'>LINK</a>";
 }

?>
```

FORM

```
<form method="post" action="your_handler.php">

<input name="dati" id="dati" style="width:310px" type="text">

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```